# Panels-style UI for arbitrary CCK fields?

Tags: drupal, cck, drupal-modules, panels, drupal-panels

I have a Drupal content type that has unlimited photo, textbox, and external link CCK fields, but while fields themselves can be reordered via drag-drop (i.e. photo B before photo A), I can't arbitrarily order amongst fields (i.e. photo B, link A, photo A, text A, link B).

Panels is awesome, with its drag and drop, and just what I'm looking for interface-wise. Has anyone seen a Panels-style UI for ordering arbitrary collections of disparate CCK fields?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do an per node ordering, I don't think that panels is the right module for you. It has a very nice interface, but it's core functionality is mostly geared towards making different types of layouts, and not micro managing content types.

I don't know of any module that can do what you are looking for, but it should not be that difficult to make a drag and drop ordering module for your content type. Drupal core has a js file that does most of the work for you, if what you want is drag and drop.

A simple solution could be if you made custom panes. Fx one for each CCK field type. In the pane form you could take an argument for the delta value. You could make it a select so the users would see the field values instead of the delta values. That would enable the panel ui.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for Panels-esque UI on a per-node basis. I know Drupal supports drag/drop via JS, but that gets messy if you mix it with CCK's multifield drag/drop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this functionality is a part of CCK 3, but that does not yet have a stable release.  Might be worth a shot to try though.

But here is a tutorial on what I think you are looking for: http://glomerate.wordpress.com/2009/11/09/a-compound-field-example-for-cck-2-and-drupal-6/

Comment: Sorry, not what I'm talking about. I'm actually running CCK3 on the site. The multigroup stuff is phenomenal, but it doesn't allow me to arbitrarily order stuff on a per-node basis.

Comment: Per *node* or per *content type*?